# Preventing php from opening in new tab/window

Tags: javascript, php

I have PHP that opens XML links in new tab.
How can I prevent such a PHP file from opening XML links in a new tab so that whenever I click on the search results the links always open on the same tab?.
And also how can I style its drop-down to remove borders around search results, and style for font colors?.

`PHP file`

```html
<?php
$xmlDoc=new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load("links.xml");

$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('link');

//get the q parameter from URL
$q=$_GET["q"];

//lookup all links from the xml file if length of q>0
if (strlen($q)>0) {
  $hint="";
  for($i=0; $i<($x->length); $i++) {
    $y=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title');
    $z=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('url');
    if ($y->item(0)->nodeType==1) {
      //find a link matching the search text
      if (stristr($y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue,$q)) {
        if ($hint=="") {
          $hint="<a href='" .
          $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue .
          "' target='_blank'>" .
          $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a>";
        } else {
          $hint=$hint . "<br /><a href='" .
          $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue .
          "' target='_blank'>" .
          $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a>";
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

// Set output to "no suggestion" if no hint was found
// or to the correct values
if ($hint=="") {
  $response="no suggestion";
} else {
  $response=$hint;
}

//output the response
echo $response;
?>
```

links.xml

```html
<link>
<title>JavaScript Date Object</title>
<url>https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp</url>
</link>
<link>
<title>JavaScript Array Object</title>
<url>https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp</url>
</link>
<link>
<title>Jordan Barton</title>
<url>https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border.asp</url>
</link>
<link>
<title>Adduli Khan</title>
<url>https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp</url>
</link>
<link>
<title>James Andrew</title>
<url>https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp</url>
</link>
</pages>
```

Comment: Just remove the `target="blank"` attribute when iterating the php node list.

Comment: Do yo mean this one $xmlDoc=new DOMDocument(); @ Marcel?. I tried but I get an error

Comment: @KamAnaniz it's better to have one request per question as this makes it easier for someone to answer. Additionally with your styling question this is very broad and would help being clearer on what you need help with exactly i.e. `How do i make the text bold?` etc.

Comment: Please share more details - opening new tabs is not a part of PHP, as this runs on the server. On the other hand, this question is tagged with Javascript, but does not contain any JS code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you add the `target="_blank"` attribute to your search results. This forces a new tab or even a new browser window.

Just change this ...

```
$hint="<a href='" .
      $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue .
      "' target='_blank'>" .
      $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a>";
```

... to this ...

```
$hint="<a href='" .
      $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue .
      "'>" .
      $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a>";
```

Comment: Thank you @Marcel!, it has worked. Excuse me, and what about styling its drop down to remove borders around search results, and style for font colors?.

Comment: We, you know the id `livesearch` of your dropdown result element. Just style it with CSS `#livesearch { ... }`.

Comment: @KamAnaniz please mark this as solved if it has resolved your issue, i'd suggest creating a new question detailing specifically your issues on the styling the search results. In that please include the CSS style code you have also

Comment: I have styled like this    #livesearch{
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 0px;
}





#livesearch a{
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: red;
  display:block;
  border: 0px;
  outline: none;
}  The color have changed, but the problem remains the border, I cannot get rid of it. With this code it remainsomething like a line on top of the search results. @Marcel

Comment: What I mean is: when I type in the search box let say letter 's' there will appear results, but those results are enclosed within a rectangular box of grey border. Now I need to get rid of this rectangle enclosing search results so that I remain with only search results.@Marcel

Comment: As @DeanWhitehouse suggested before, mark this question as solved and create a new question with detailed informations about your style issue.